# Project Euler #2 Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to solve Project Euler problems with Ruby by trying to build solutions that are similar to what the solution in plain English would be. PEuler #2 states "...By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms". I formulated a plain English solution like "Add indexes -1 and -2 and push them to an array. Repeat the operation while index -1 is less than 4 millions. Then take each number in the array and divide it by two. Take those whose math residue is 0, add them and print the result". Here is the code I have:

```
seq = [1, 2, 3]
sum = 0
num = 33

while seq[-1] < num do seq.push(seq[-1] + seq[-2]) end
seq.each {|i| if i%2 == 0 then sum += i end}

puts sum
```

Any ideas on how to provide a solution following this logic? And, programmatically, how correct it is to solve it this way?

Comment: What's your problem here?

Comment: Yeah your logic is correct, if you change num to `4000000` then you should have the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like this, which adds up the even numbers in the sequence as they are encountered. That has the advantage that only the previous two elements in the sequence are required, so the memory that the `seq` array used is saved, and it avoids a scan through the entire list once it has been built

```
max = 4_000_000
a, b = 2, 3
sum = 2

while (c = a + b) < max do
  sum += c if c % 2 == 0
  a, b = b, c
end

puts sum
```

Comment: @maerics: I haven't heard of Project Euler. Flag my answer if you wish

Comment: It's a fairly popular website of several programming problems that get increasingly difficult (https://projecteuler.net/).  No real harm in posting a solution, I suppose it's just as uncool to post a SO question asking for one.  Not sure if the SO community has an opinion about that sort of thing.

Comment: Some interesting commentary here http://forum.projecteuler.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2707